# onmouseover tooltip is not shown correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-visualization

I am using [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)and Google column chart to display the data in the form of charts.
When the data is more, i am showing the chart with horizontal scrollbar. Issue is with tooltip when the scrollbar is on.

Please find the demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/a5ye364evZtXUs7xjABR?p=preview).

When mouse over on the bars, it shows the information of the bar in the tooltip. Scroll to the end of the bar using horizontal scrollbar in the demo plunker above and mouseover to see the issue, the tooltip is not displayed correctly. It only happens when trying to view the data after scrolling horizontally.

Noticed the issue with the below property:

```
 focusTarget: 'category'
```

If i remove the above propery tooltip is displayed correctly but i want that property to use in my application.Any suggestions?

Sample [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        c: [{
          v: "January"
        }, {
          v: 19,
          f: "42 items"
        }, {
          v: 12,
          f: "Ony 12 items"
        }, {
          v: 7,
          f: "7 servers"
        }, {
          v: 4
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }, {
          v: 12
        }, {
          v: 2
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "April"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "September"
          }, {
            v: 4
          }, {
            v: 2
          }, {
            v: 51
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "October"
          }, {
            v: 34
          }, {
            v: 4
          }, {
            v: 0
          }, {
            v: 1
          }

        ]
      }]
    };
    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "isStacked": "true",
      "fill": 20,
      focusTarget: 'category',
      "displayExactValues": true,
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date"
      },
      "width": chart1.data.rows.length * 130,
      "bar": {
        groupWidth: 40
      }
    };
    chart1.view = {
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;

    $scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) {
      console.log(selectedItem);
      var col = selectedItem.column;
      if (selectedItem.row === null) {
        console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
        if ($scope.myChart.view.columns[col] == col) {
          $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = {
            label: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].label,
            type: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].type,
            calc: function() {
              return null;
            }
          };

          $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = '#CCCCCC';
        } else {
          console.log("Ran this.");
          $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
          console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
          $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[col - 1];
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `<div google-chart chart="myChart">` inside another `<div>` with the required style.

```
<div style="width: 60%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div google-chart chart="myChart"></div>
</div>
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  /**
   * @description Google Chart Api Directive Module for AngularJS
   * @version 0.0.10
   * @author Nicolas Bouillon <nicolas@bouil.org>
   * @author GitHub contributors
   * @license MIT
   * @year 2013
   */
  (function(document, window, angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('googlechart', [])

      .value('googleChartApiConfig', {
        version: '1',
        optionalSettings: {
          packages: ['corechart']
        }
      })

      .provider('googleJsapiUrl', function() {
        var protocol = 'https:';
        var url = '//www.google.com/jsapi';

        this.setProtocol = function(newProtocol) {
          protocol = newProtocol;
        };

        this.setUrl = function(newUrl) {
          url = newUrl;
        };

        this.$get = function() {
          return (protocol ? protocol : '') + url;
        };
      })
      .factory('googleChartApiPromise', ['$rootScope', '$q', 'googleChartApiConfig', 'googleJsapiUrl', function($rootScope, $q, apiConfig, googleJsapiUrl) {
        var apiReady = $q.defer();
        var onLoad = function() {
          // override callback function
          var settings = {
            callback: function() {
              var oldCb = apiConfig.optionalSettings.callback;
              $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                apiReady.resolve();
              });

              if (angular.isFunction(oldCb)) {
                oldCb.call(this);
              }
            }
          };

          settings = angular.extend({}, apiConfig.optionalSettings, settings);

          window.google.load('visualization', apiConfig.version, settings);
        };
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');

        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.src = googleJsapiUrl;

        if (script.addEventListener) { // Standard browsers (including IE9+)
          script.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);
        } else { // IE8 and below
          script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
              script.onreadystatechange = null;
              onLoad();
            }
          };
        }

        head.appendChild(script);

        return apiReady.promise;
      }])
      .directive('googleChart', ['$timeout', '$window', '$rootScope', 'googleChartApiPromise', function($timeout, $window, $rootScope, googleChartApiPromise) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
            beforeDraw: '&',
            chart: '=chart',
            onReady: '&',
            onSelect: '&',
            select: '&'
          },
          link: function($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
            /* Watches, to refresh the chart when its data, formatters, options, or type change.
                All other values intentionally disregarded to avoid double calls to the draw
                function. Please avoid making changes to these objects directly from this directive.*/
            $scope.$watch(function() {
              if ($scope.chart) {
                return {
                  data: $scope.chart.data,
                  formatters: $scope.chart.formatters,
                  options: $scope.chart.options,
                  type: $scope.chart.type,
                  customFormatters: $scope.chart.customFormatters,
                  view: $scope.chart.view
                };
              }
              return $scope.chart;
            }, function() {
              drawAsync();
            }, true); // true is for deep object equality checking

            // Redraw the chart if the window is resized
            var resizeHandler = $rootScope.$on('resizeMsg', function() {
              $timeout(function() {
                // Not always defined yet in IE so check
                if ($scope.chartWrapper) {
                  drawAsync();
                }
              });
            });

            //Cleanup resize handler.
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              resizeHandler();
            });

            // Keeps old formatter configuration to compare against
            $scope.oldChartFormatters = {};

            function applyFormat(formatType, formatClass, dataTable) {

              if (typeof($scope.chart.formatters[formatType]) != 'undefined') {
                if (!angular.equals($scope.chart.formatters[formatType], $scope.oldChartFormatters[formatType])) {
                  $scope.oldChartFormatters[formatType] = $scope.chart.formatters[formatType];
                  $scope.formatters[formatType] = [];

                  if (formatType === 'color') {
                    for (var cIdx = 0; cIdx < $scope.chart.formatters[formatType].length; cIdx++) {
                      var colorFormat = new formatClass();

                      for (i = 0; i < $scope.chart.formatters[formatType][cIdx].formats.length; i++) {
                        var data = $scope.chart.formatters[formatType][cIdx].formats[i];

                        if (typeof(data.fromBgColor) != 'undefined' && typeof(data.toBgColor) != 'undefined')
                          colorFormat.addGradientRange(data.from, data.to, data.color, data.fromBgColor, data.toBgColor);
                        else
                          colorFormat.addRange(data.from, data.to, data.color, data.bgcolor);
                      }

                      $scope.formatters[formatType].push(colorFormat);
                    }
                  } else {

                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.chart.formatters[formatType].length; i++) {
                      $scope.formatters[formatType].push(new formatClass(
                        $scope.chart.formatters[formatType][i]));
                    }
                  }
                }


                //apply formats to dataTable
                for (i = 0; i < $scope.formatters[formatType].length; i++) {
                  if ($scope.chart.formatters[formatType][i].columnNum < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns())
                    $scope.formatters[formatType][i].format(dataTable, $scope.chart.formatters[formatType][i].columnNum);
                }


                //Many formatters require HTML tags to display special formatting
                if (formatType === 'arrow' || formatType === 'bar' || formatType === 'color')
                  $scope.chart.options.allowHtml = true;
              }
            }

            function draw() {
              if (!draw.triggered && ($scope.chart !== undefined)) {
                draw.triggered = true;
                $timeout(function() {

                  if (typeof($scope.chartWrapper) == 'undefined') {
                    var chartWrapperArgs = {
                      chartType: $scope.chart.type,
                      dataTable: $scope.chart.data,
                      view: $scope.chart.view,
                      options: $scope.chart.options,
                      containerId: $elm[0]
                    };

                    $scope.chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(chartWrapperArgs);
                    google.visualization.events.addListener($scope.chartWrapper, 'ready', function() {
                      $scope.chart.displayed = true;
                      $scope.$apply(function(scope) {
                        scope.onReady({
                          chartWrapper: scope.chartWrapper
                        });
                      });
                    });
                    google.visualization.events.addListener($scope.chartWrapper, 'error', function(err) {
                      console.log("Chart not displayed due to error: " + err.message + ". Full error object follows.");
                      console.log(err);
                    });
                    google.visualization.events.addListener($scope.chartWrapper, 'select', function() {
                      var selectedItem = $scope.chartWrapper.getChart().getSelection()[0];
                      $scope.$apply(function() {
                        if ($attrs.select) {
                          console.log('Angular-Google-Chart: The \'select\' attribute is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Please use \'onSelect\'.');
                          $scope.select({
                            selectedItem: selectedItem
                          });
                        } else {
                          $scope.onSelect({
                            selectedItem: selectedItem
                          });
                        }
                      });
                    });
                  } else {
                    $scope.chartWrapper.setChartType($scope.chart.type);
                    $scope.chartWrapper.setDataTable($scope.chart.data);
                    $scope.chartWrapper.setView($scope.chart.view);
                    $scope.chartWrapper.setOptions($scope.chart.options);
                  }

                  if (typeof($scope.formatters) === 'undefined')
                    $scope.formatters = {};

                  if (typeof($scope.chart.formatters) != 'undefined') {
                    applyFormat("number", google.visualization.NumberFormat, $scope.chartWrapper.getDataTable());
                    applyFormat("arrow", google.visualization.ArrowFormat, $scope.chartWrapper.getDataTable());
                    applyFormat("date", google.visualization.DateFormat, $scope.chartWrapper.getDataTable());
                    applyFormat("bar", google.visualization.BarFormat, $scope.chartWrapper.getDataTable());
                    applyFormat("color", google.visualization.ColorFormat, $scope.chartWrapper.getDataTable());
                  }

                  var customFormatters = $scope.chart.customFormatters;
                  if (typeof(customFormatters) != 'undefined') {
                    for (var name in customFormatters) {
                      applyFormat(name, customFormatters[name], $scope.chartWrapper.getDataTable());
                    }
                  }

                  $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.beforeDraw({
                      chartWrapper: $scope.chartWrapper
                    });
                    $scope.chartWrapper.draw();
                    draw.triggered = false;
                  });
                }, 0, true);
              }
            }

            function drawAsync() {
              googleChartApiPromise.then(function() {
                draw();
              });
            }
          }
        };
      }])

      .run(['$rootScope', '$window', function($rootScope, $window) {
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
          $rootScope.$emit('resizeMsg');
        });
      }]);

  })(document, window, window.angular);





  angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope) {
      var chart1 = {};
      chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
      chart1.displayed = false;
      chart1.data = {
        "cols": [{
          id: "month",
          label: "Month",
          type: "string"
        }, {
          id: "laptop-id",
          label: "Laptop",
          type: "number"
        }, {
          id: "desktop-id",
          label: "Desktop",
          type: "number"
        }, {
          id: "server-id",
          label: "Server",
          type: "number"
        }, {
          id: "cost-id",
          label: "Shipping",
          type: "number"
        }],
        "rows": [{
          c: [{
            v: "January"
          }, {
            v: 19,
            f: "42 items"
          }, {
            v: 12,
            f: "Ony 12 items"
          }, {
            v: 7,
            f: "7 servers"
          }, {
            v: 4
          }]
        }, {
          c: [{
            v: "February"
          }, {
            v: 13
          }, {
            v: 1,
            f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
          }, {
            v: 12
          }, {
            v: 2
          }]
        }, {
          c: [{
              v: "March"
            }, {
              v: 24
            }, {
              v: 5
            }, {
              v: 11
            }, {
              v: 6
            }

          ]
        }, {
          c: [{
              v: "April"
            }, {
              v: 24
            }, {
              v: 5
            }, {
              v: 11
            }, {
              v: 6
            }

          ]
        }, {
          c: [{
              v: "May"
            }, {
              v: 18
            }, {
              v: 11
            }, {
              v: 7
            }, {
              v: 2
            }

          ]
        }, {
          c: [{
              v: "June"
            }, {
              v: 21
            }, {
              v: 5
            }, {
              v: 8
            }, {
              v: 6
            }

          ]
        }, {
          c: [{
              v: "July"
            }, {
              v: 24
            }, {
              v: 5
            }, {
              v: 9
            }, {
              v: 9
            }

          ]
        }, {
          c: [{
              v: "August"
            }, {
              v: 14
            }, {
              v: 1
            }, {
              v: 11
            }, {
              v: 5
            }

          ]
        }, {
          c: [{
              v: "September"
            }, {
              v: 4
            }, {
              v: 2
            }, {
              v: 51
            }, {
              v: 6
            }

          ]
        }, {
          c: [{
              v: "October"
            }, {
              v: 34
            }, {
              v: 4
            }, {
              v: 0
            }, {
              v: 1
            }

          ]
        }]
      };
      chart1.options = {
        "title": "Sales per month",
        "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
        "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
        "isStacked": "true",
        "fill": 20,
        focusTarget: 'category',
        "displayExactValues": true,
        "vAxis": {
          "title": "Sales unit",
          "gridlines": {
            "count": 10
          }
        },
        "hAxis": {
          "title": "Date"
        },
        "width": chart1.data.rows.length * 130,
        "bar": {
          groupWidth: 40
        }
      };
      chart1.view = {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
      };
      $scope.myChart = chart1;

      $scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) {
        console.log(selectedItem);
        var col = selectedItem.column;
        //If there's no row value, user clicked the legend.
        if (selectedItem.row === null) {
          //If true, the chart series is currently displayed normally.  Hide it.
          console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
          if ($scope.myChart.view.columns[col] == col) {
            //Replace the integer value with this object initializer.
            $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = {
              //Take the label value and type from the existing column.
              label: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].label,
              type: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].type,
              //makes the new column a calculated column based on a function that returns null, 
              //effectively hiding the series.
              calc: function() {
                return null;
              }
            };
            //Change the series color to grey to indicate that it is hidden.
            //Uses color[col-1] instead of colors[col] because the domain column (in my case the date values)
            //does not need a color value.
            $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = '#CCCCCC';
          }
          //series is currently hidden, bring it back.
          else {
            console.log("Ran this.");
            //Simply reassigning the integer column index value removes the calculated column.
            $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
            console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
            //I had the original colors already backed up in another array.  If you want to do this in a more
            //dynamic way (say if the user could change colors for example), then you'd need to have them backed
            //up when you switch to grey.
            $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[col - 1];
          }
        }
      };
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="myController">
    <div style="width: 60%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;">
      <div data-google-chart data-chart="myChart"></div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div data-google-chart data-chart="myChart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```